# Ionic 1.2.4 and button bar border transparent

Tags: css, ionic-framework

In Ionic 1.2.4 i have added a button bar but the button doesn't have any border (instead in the official documentation they have a border).

I have:

```
<div class="button-bar bar-stable">
   <a class="button">First</a>
   <a class="button">Second</a>
   <a class="button">Third</a>
</div>
```

I've seen that in the css:

```
.bar-stable .button {
   border-color: transparent;
   background-color: #f8f8f8;
   color: #444; }
```

Why the Ionic Team has make the

```
border-color: transparent ?
```

In the Ionic Creator i see the following css code:

```
.bar-stable .button {
  border-color: #b2b2b2;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #444; }
```

but it use a css version 1.1.1

Comment: I really don't understand why it should be transparent

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately in ionic 1.2.0 the border of buttons was removed and there seems to be no general solution.

Look here [Defaulting all button borders to transparent #4861](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4861)

I'm currently fighting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used inline styling (bad practice I know) as a workaround to this problem to apply a border to an individual button without having to interfere with the button class. Like so:

```
<button style="border-right: 2px solid #15AB3F;" class="button button-block button-balanced"></button>
```